# How can I sign in after upgrading to a 'Mojang' account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I was playing Minecraft and then I changed my skin. It said that I can migrate my old Minecraft account into a Mojang account, so I did.

However I cannot log in anymore. Then after 5 tries of the same thing I got in but couldn't play multiplayer because it says I wasn't authorized. Is it because Microsoft bought Mojang? Because I fully bought Minecraft a while ago.

Comment: Did you try loggin in with your email?

Answer (score 2):

You simply use your e-mail (The one your Mojang account uses) as your username and your old password